# Linearity of a Given Functional

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $f$ be a functional from the set of all sequences with only finitely many nonzero terms, $c_o$, to a field $\mathbb{F}$ (real or complex). $f$ is defined by a series from $n=0$ to infinity $\frac{x_n}{n!}$.

Show that $f$ is linear, continuous, $\lVert f\rVert=e$ but there is no $x$ in the closed unit ball of $c_o$ such that $\lvert f(x)\rvert=\lVert f\rVert.$

Comment: What norm are you using?

Comment: Supremum norm ||x||=sup|x_n|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $s_n = \sum_{k=0}^n {1 \over k!}$. Note that $s_n$ is a strictly
increasing sequence and $s_n \uparrow e$.

Furthermore, suppose $a_n \in [0,1]$, then $\sum_{k=0}^\infty {a_n \over k!} \le e$ and $\sum_{k=0}^\infty {a_n \over k!} = e$ **iff** $a_n = 1$ for all $n$.

$|f(x)| \le \sum_n { |x_n| \over n!} \le \sum_n { \|x\| \over n!} = e \|x\|$.
Hence $\|f\| \le e$.

Since $s_n \to e$, we see that if $x_n = (1,...,1,0,...)$
(that is, exactly $n$ contiguous ones), then $\|x_n\| = 1$ and
$f(x_n) = s_n$, and so
$f(x_n) \to e$. Hence $\|f \| = e$.

Suppose $\|x\| \le 1$ and $|f(x)| = e$. Then
$\sum_n { |x_n| \over n!} = e$ and so $|x_n| = 1$ for all $n$ which is
a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you. What if f is defined on the space of all sequences converging to 0 ? Could we conclude the same results?

Comment: Yes. The above proof works in that case too.